# replacing an element in a list c#

Tags: c#, list, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I want to replace "Mutate" an element from a list, by taking some other random element from another list.

```
private int elitism = 20;
private int population = 1;
private int chance = 100;
private Random rand = new Random();
private List<HeroStats> allHeroes = new List<HeroStats>();
private List<Team> allTeams = new List<Team>();
```

If I create a team and mutate it, it should replace 1 random element from that current team, but if I use yhe `Mutation` Method , the replacement doesn't occur; I get the same team

```
public void Mutation()
{
    // compute how many individuals will 100% survive
    int goodResults= population * elitism / 100;
    int index;
    int position;
    HeroStats old_hero, new_hero;
    Team new_team;

    for (int i = goodResults; i < allTeams.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (rand.Next(0, 100) < chance)
        {
            new_team = allTeams.ElementAt(i);
            index = allTeams.IndexOf(new_team);
            // select random hero within the team , a team having 5 heros
            position = rand.Next(0, 4);
            //RetrieveHero(int x) is a method which returns the hero from position x within a team
            old_hero = new_team.RetrieveHero(position);
            // get a new hero from the hero-list
            new_hero = allHeroes.ElementAt(rand.Next(0, 101));
            // associate the new value to the genome
            new_team.Remove(old_hero);
            new_team.Add(new_hero);
            allTeams[index] = new_team;
        }
    }
}
```

As an example : consider team a = [ 1 2 3 4 5]

 After the `team a` undergoes a Mutation , it could look like this
 team a = [1, 2, 3, 4, R] , or team a = [1, P, 3, 4, 5] , or team a = [1, 2, 3, 99, 5]

Why is my code behaving so strange ?

Comment: what is the expected output or what are you getting that makes it act so strange?

Comment: What exactly is it doing that makes you think it's acting strangely?

Comment: I tested it by creating only 1 team , printing it , using the method on that team and printing the new team again, it does not change anything

Comment: Could you please try to remove unrelated code from your sample and at the same time make scope of variables as small as possible. Also there is complicated code that implements `index=i` (`index=allTeams.IndexOf(allTeams.ElementAt(i))` with unclear purpose - see if you can clean it up too.

Comment: Not suggesting this is the case, but since you do not seed Random you're probably getting the same exact sequence each time you're running your program. If you're extremely unlucky the rand.Next will correspond to the unit already at that index.

Comment: also, i and index will be the same no need to ask for IndexOf when you just used ElementAt

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig The default constructor for `Random` uses the current time for the seed. You're the second one to suggest this (the first was a now-deleted answer). I'm surprised that this isn't more commonly known.

Comment: Really? I did not realize that, but thanks for letting me know. I've definitely experienced bugs with this but that's probably in `UnityEngine.Random`. I still do think it's nice to be explicit with the seed though (for instance if the consumer of the class/api sets system time for some reason..).

Comment: using a static random is a lot better than an instacne since you are on the subject

Comment: As it stands, the code looks fine (the last assignment does absolutely nothing, but it shouldn't hurt anything). Could you check/show the `Add` and `Remove` methods? Are you sure you ever get inside the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes I get into the `if` statement since I checked with some prints , they were in this section of the code ( the one I've put on StackOverflow) but the result was simply the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work around the problem by adding a method inside the `Team` class :

```
public void ReplaceHero(HeroStats hero,HeroStats new_Hero)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++ )
                if (team.ElementAt(i).Equals(hero))
                {
                    team.Remove(hero);
                    team.Add(new_Hero);
                }
        }
```

If there are any improvements that I could make, I would really appreciate to know about them.